# Why some websites are redirected to microsoft edge?

Tags: internet-explorer

I tried to open https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifCWN5pJGIE

And I got redirected to microsoft edge.

The thing is I want it to be opened in internet explorer. It's my alarm in case something need to be done. My program will turn it off again.

And it used to open just fine in internet explorer. In other computers it opens just fine in internet explorer.

How do I turn of this stupid feature

It redirects here.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/the-website-you-were-trying-to-reach-doesn-t-work-with-internet-explorer-8f5fc675-cd47-414c-9535-12821ddfc554?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Should I open the mobile version instead or is there a work around.

Comment: Internet Explorer is end of life. Edge now has a legacy IE 11 mode if it proves necessary, otherwise just use Edge..

Comment: Additionally, Microsoft officially has announced the formal End of Life date for IE11.  Google has always only supported browsers that are officially supported.  Internet Explorer 11 was only in maintenance.  Google has often taken it upon themselves to discontinue the support of browsers on their services.

Comment: If you don't want to use Edge, then you need to use a third-party browser such as Firefox or Chrome (and Edge is now based on Chrome).